# .NET Attributes on Property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

If I have:

```
[SomeAttr]
public Int32 SomeProperty
{
  get; set;
}
```

Is it possible for `SomeAttr` to tell what property it's tacked onto? Is it atleast possible to tell what `Type` the `property` is?

Comment: where do you get SomeAttr "list" from ? From a type, no ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want my attribute to have different behaviour depending on the type of the property

Comment: Focus on how you *retrieve* an attribute, GetCustomAttribute() method.  You'll see the chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: That's how I've always done it in the past... I was just trying to see if I was missing an opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Not directly.

What you can do, at the moment you collect the attribute, is set that attribute with extra information:

```
class SomeAttr: Attribute
{
    public PropertyInfo Target {get;set;}
}
```

... and when you have collected the information:

```
Type type = ... // The type which holds the property.
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeo.GetProperty("SomeProperty");
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
SomeAttr attr = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<SomeAttr>().FirstOrDefault();
attr.Target = propertyInfo; // <== Set the target information.
```

This way, you can always retrieve its target member at another point in your code:

```
public void DoSomethingWithAttribute(SomeAttr attr)
{
    PropertyInfo whichProperty = attr.Target;
}
```

(You can also use the baseclass `MemberInfo`, to support methods, fields, etc.)

Comment: Looks like we posted simultanuously

Comment: @Frank: With a 3 minutes difference. :)

Comment: @Andre: I modified my answer. Perhaps this will work a little better.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only do it the other way around. You can query the property (through reflection) what attributes it has:

> Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(prop, true);

Where prop is an object derived from the MemberInfo class that describes the property SomeProperty. Next you iterate through the returned attributes to see if it includes yours.